# Activity Recognition using new GoogleApiClient not firing Activity Updates

Tags: android, activity-recognition

I am trying to set up ActivityRecognition in my app using the new GoogleApiClient. I couldn't find any documentation anywhere (Official android docs still refer to the now deprecated ActivityRecognitionClient).

The code that I managed to write is not triggering Activity Updates.

1) Inside my MainActivity's onCreate :

```
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(ActivityRecognition.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();

mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

2) Inside onConnected :

```
    Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityRecognitionIntentService.class);
    PendingIntent mActivityRecognitionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Log.e("Aditya", "Connected to ActRec");
    ActivityRecognitionApi actRecAPI = new ActivityRecognitionApi()
    {
        public PendingResult<Status> requestActivityUpdates(GoogleApiClient googleApiClient, long l, PendingIntent pendingIntent)
        {
            Log.e("Aditya", "inside requestActivityUpdates()");
            return null;
        }

        public PendingResult<Status> removeActivityUpdates(GoogleApiClient googleApiClient, PendingIntent pendingIntent)
        {
            return null;
        }
    };

    actRecAPI.requestActivityUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, 0, mActivityRecognitionPendingIntent);
```

My ActivityRecognitionIntentService never receives an update.

What am I doing wrong? Or is there any sort of documentation on ActivityRecognition through GoogleApiClient anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it. After connecting to GoogleApiClient I just had to do this to start receiving Activity Updates.

```
ActivityRecognition.ActivityRecognitionApi.
  requestActivityUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, 0, mActivityRecognitionPendingIntent);
```

No need to create your own ActivityRecognitionApi object.

Comment: Here is the documentation : https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/ActivityRecognitionApi